# Firefox, Chromium on Debian: WebRTC H.264 is not supported

Tags: debian, firefox, streaming, video-encoding

While trying to stream online with my friends, I had an issue where everyone else's computer can watch the stream but mine, and even my android device can watch it.

I found [this test page from GitHub Mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/pc_test_no_h264.html) that revealed I don't have H.264 support for WebRTC, while all my friends did.

- I tested this on Firefox 112.0.1, both the Debian package `firefox` and the build from the official website.
- I tested this on Chromium 112.0.5615.138 (Official Build) built on Debian 12.0, running on Debian 12.0 (64-bit) (provided by Debian package `chromium`).
- I have installed `libx264-160` and `libx264-164`.
- I have installed `libopenh264-7`. Replacing it with competitor `libopenh264-cisco7` makes no improvement.
- I can watch H.264 encoded videos offline with MPV and VLC.
- `ffmpeg -codec` lists h264 support: `DEV.LS h264       H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10`

Nearly all documents and SE questions about H.264 support for Firefox are dated from around 2014-2017, which I infer this means this is an old, solved issue. If that's the case, why isn't Firefox detecting support for H.264?

I use Debian Unstable (next release bookworm).

Comment: Can you try Debian Live? Or create another user and try to run it from that other session.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469371/ubuntu-23-04-firefox-ppa-no-decoder-found-for-audio-mp4a-latm This is my story on trying to get a working .deb version of firefox. I now give up for the 3rd time. Proximus TV and Netflix just don't work due to the absence of H264 and AAC in about:support section Media. I just switched back to SNAP and everything works fine !!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue when trying to use go2rtc WebRTC interface with Firefox. It turns out that there's a preference called `media.webrtc.hw.h264.enabled` that by [default disables h.264 WebRTC decoder if hardware acceleration is used](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1717679). Turning it on in `about:config` fixes this issue.